# anchor tag download attribute works for Cross origin links

Tags: html, anchor

I've read in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) that the download attribute for anchor tag works only for the same origin urls.
But my code below seems to work in chrome, though the url is of cross origin.

```html
<body>
<a download href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a'>
  Click me to download the file
</a>
</body>
```

When I click on the link, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) page is being downloaded in chrome(57.0.2987).

But it works as expected on Firefox(53.0.2). Why so?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please see that it's working on firefox. But not chrome

Comment: It is not working now. Read this [chrome feature update doc](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4969697975992320)